# Setting Tab Bar Image Insets

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have subclassed UITabBarController, and am setting my tab bar image insets in its viewDidLoad as follows:

```
UITabBarItem *feedBarItem = self.tabBar.items[0];
[feedBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"feed_icon"]];
[feedBarItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)];
feedBarItem.title = @"FEED";
```

When I navigate to another VC in the tab bar, the image insets reset to 0 for some reason. When I navigate back, they are correctly set to 6. Why is this happening?

Its almost as if the insets are only working when the tab bar item is selected..